# ruby gedcom parser EOF exception

Tags: ruby, parsing, gedcom

i need to parse gedcom 5.5 files for a analyziation project.
The first ruby parser i found couses a stack level too deep error, so i tryed to find alternatives. I fount this project: https://github.com/jslade/gedcom-ruby

There are some samples included, but i don't get them to work either.

Here is the parser itself: https://github.com/jslade/gedcom-ruby/blob/master/lib/gedcom.rb

If i try the sample like this:

```
ruby ./samples/count.rb ./samples/royal.ged
```

i get the following error:

```
D:/rails_projects/gedom_test/lib/gedcom.rb:185:in `readchar': end of file reached (EOFError)
```

I wrote a "gets" in every method for better unterstanding, this is the output till the exception raises:

```
Parsing './samples/royal.ged'...
INIT
BEFORE
CHECK_PROC_OR_BLOCK
BEFORE
CHECK_PROC_OR_BLOCK
PARSE
PARSE_FILE
PARSE_IO
DETECT_RS
```

The exact line that causes the trouble is

```
while ch = io.readchar
```

in the detect_rs method:

```
# valid gedcom may use either of \r or \r\n as the record separator.
# just in case, also detects simple \n as the separator as well
# detects the rs for this string by scanning ahead to the first occurence
# of either \r or \n, and checking the character after it
def detect_rs io
puts "DETECT_RS"
  rs = "\x0d"
  mark = io.pos
  begin
    while ch = io.readchar
      case ch
      when 0x0d
        ch2 = io.readchar
        if ch2 == 0x0a
          rs = "\x0d\x0a"
        end
        break
      when 0x0a
        rs = "\x0a"
        break
      end
    end
  ensure
    io.pos = mark
  end
  rs
end
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `readchar` method of Ruby's `IO` class will raise an `EOFError` when it encounters the end of the file.  http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-i-readchar

The `gedcom-ruby` gem hasn't been touched in years, but there was a fork of it made a couple of years go to fix this very problem.

Basically it changes:

```
while ch = io.readchar
```

to

```
while !io.eof && ch = io.readchar
```

You can get the fork of the gem here: https://github.com/trentlarson/gedcom-ruby

Comment: Thank you, that solves the exception problem, but it doesn't really work right now either.
It says that the file does not contain any persons, which can't be correct:
There are 0 individuals and 0 families in 'samples/royal.ged'.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about gedcom files - I was just trying to get you past the EOF error.  However just to see, I downloaded gedcom from the fork in my answer and when I run `ruby samples/count.rb samples/royal.ged` it gives me `There are 3010 individuals and 1422 families in 'samples/royal.ged'.`.

Comment: Yeah.. i'm using ruby and rails on a windows machine, i tryed the same exact example on a virtual linux machine and get the correct output.